# What is the difference between Layout and Design?

Tags: design-patterns, layout, graphics, design-principles

I can't understand what is `Design` and what is `Layout` in the web-design. I'm confused about layout and design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Layout**:

1. Deals with structure of the main content of a single page. A part of web-design that deals in the arrangement of visual elements on a webpage. It generally involves organizational principles of composition to achieve specific communication objectives.
2. Three main content areas organized in a pattern of your choice.
3. Body of the page, and if there's a main title and also where all main content appears.
4. In computing, **layout** is the process of calculating the position of objects in space subject to various constraints. Page layout is the computation of the position of the paragraphs, tabs, sentences, words and letters of a text.
5. A website **wireframe** is a low-cost way to show layouts.

**Design**:

1. Deals with aesthetics and overall look of the site.
2. Color scheme, basic page setup and often background image(s).
3. Helps to determine where your site title, page title, and footer are on each page
4. Design is the creation of a plan or convention for the construction of an object or a system.